# How to setup imports for a dart/polymer project (in general and for BWU-datagrid)

Tags: import, dart, dart-polymer, bwu-datagrid

I've tried examples from Learning Dart, the Dart website, Up and Running and I can't get this to work.  I've read and tried everything I know to and I still do not understand dart imports.

I am simply trying to setup my own bwu_datagrid and I finding the imports to be impossible because when I do what is suggested or I run the exact code from say the Learning Dart examples and it doesn't work.

So can someone explain to me, in detail, what I need to do to make a dart project where a bwu_datagrid is rendered on screen without error.

my project structure is:

- /root

  - /packages

    - /bwu_datagrid
    - /polymer
    - ...other packages
  - /lib

    - /src

      - some_part.dart
    - some_library.dart
  - /web

    - index.html

Comment: I think it's a good idea to always add the [dart] tag. I for example monitor only this Dart related tag on StackOverflow and other tags only occassionally. I guess this question is already answered here https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!topic/web/_fo3H6Ep9D4

Answer (score 1):

There are different types of imports:

- `import 'dart:blah';` Imports from the Dart SDK, eg. `dart:html`
- `import 'package:blah/something.dart';` Imports from a package that you've included via Pub (in your `pubspec.yaml`), which will appear as a symlink inside your `packages` folders (which get symlinked in several places, like `bin\packages` and `web\packages`
- `import 'path/file.dart';` Imports a file from the file system using a relative path

Something that confused me at first, is that if you want to import something from your own project without putting a path that's relative to where the including file is, you can import using a `package:` prefix and your own project name. This works, because Pub creates a symlink for your own project inside the packages folder.

Eg.:

`my_project\web\packages\my_project` is a symlink back to `my_project\lib` so that you can do:

```
import 'package:my_project/my_stuff.dart';
```

So, in order to import something from `bwu_datagrid`, which is a pub package, you need to do:

```
import 'package:bwu_datagrid/somefile.dart';
```

You need to replace `somefile.dart` with the correct file that you need to include, as you do not import "packages" directly; but rather files from within them.